# why library contract still exist after killed by devs99 on 6 Nov?

Tags: contract-development, etherscan, parity-wallet

everyone.
I'm new to Ethereum, here's a little question about parity wallet hacking on 6 Nov.

Parity wallet security issue happened again. We all know this is because he called kill function to kill the library contract. But after I checked this transaction on etherscan, it doesn't show this is the last transaction on this contract. I'm confused by why library contract can still keeping its transaction with other accounts, which also called initWallet() again.
I think library contract was killed, which means removed from blockchain forever and can not be used anymore....

**Library Contract Address** : 0x863DF6BFa4469f3ead0bE8f9F2AAE51c91A907b4

**Transaction on etherscan** 
https://etherscan.io/address/0x863df6bfa4469f3ead0be8f9f2aae51c91a907b4[image]

**hackers address** :0xae7168deb52586...(just two txs)

Comment: still confused, help pls:(

Comment: This comment fom a developer may help to understand https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/pull/42#issuecomment-160237928. A selfdestruct only removes the contract code from the world state, but the contract address still exists, it can receive ether, and tokens. If you make a call to the contract address it will be ignored, like any other address without code.

Comment: thanks for the link to this comment, it's helpful. I want to ask what's "address without code"? can you give me an example? thanks

Comment: In Ethereum you have two type of accounts "external owned accounts" and "contracts", the only difference is that contracts have a "code" with the bytecode of the contract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll note that on the 'contract code' tab is is tagged as 'Suicide'.

The history of a self destructed contract doesn't disappear because it's on the blockchain.  Instead the contract's bytecode stored in state is removed allowing non-archival nodes to free up some space.